# jQuery val() comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to compare the values of two input fields with jQuery. However, it does seem correct but it doesn't `alert` when one of the values is larger.

```
Enter the key:
<input type="text" name="key" size="35" id="q17" autocomplete="off">
<input id="charsLeft" type="text" class="count1" disabled>

<br /><br />

Plaintext:
<input type="text" name="key" size="35" id="q18" autocomplete="off">
<input id="charsLeft2" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" type="text" class="count" disabled>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Count key
  $("#q17").keyup(function() {
      $('#charsLeft').val($(this).val().length);
  });
  // Count plaintext
  $("#q18").keyup(function() {
      $('#charsLeft2').val($(this).val().length);
  });
  // Compare key|plaintext
  if ($('#charsLeft').val() < $('#charsLeft2').val()) {
    alert('Key is shorter than the plaintext');
  }
});
```

I am trying to compare the values of the two input fields (`charsLeft` and `charsLeft2`). What am I missing here? Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mgzn4pL/

Comment: just use `+$('#charsLeft').val() < +$('#charsLeft2').val()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing strings, not integers. You can use `parseInt()` to convert them. Try this:

```
if (parseInt($('#charsLeft').val(), 10) < parseInt($('#charsLeft2').val(), 10)) {
    alert('Key is shorter than the plaintext');
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mgzn4pL/1/)

Comment: Or just `+$('#charsLeft2').val()`.

Comment: True, but be aware that the `+` unary operator is equivalent to using `Number()`, not `parseInt()`

Comment: Just for the record, the second argument to `parseInt` is the radix, (i.e. the base of the number).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I did check up on the function once you posted your answer. However, how can I run the check without the need of an action (i.e. the click event in this case)?

Comment: I ended up using `.focusout()` as mentioned below but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

`.val()` returns a string. You should use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: That's exactly what I had forgotten. Thank you for your time and answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There a two problems with your code:

1. You're comparing string values with `.val()` not string lengths
2. Your comparison code is executed on page load - which means only when the page has loaded you'll see the result, but on this event the result is false and nothing is being alerted.

For the first problem you should compare string lengths this way `$('#charsLeft').val().length < $('#charsLeft2').val().length`.

For the second problem you should put your comparison code in a button's click event handler function or something in this sort. Another option is to use the `focusout` event of the second input and attach an event handler with [`.focusout()`](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

Comment: `.focusout()` is somewhat what I was looking for. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Glad to help you! :) You can evaluate my answer :)